# Pass multiple values from java to jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

Hello I am trying to pass parameters from java to jsp file. But I am not getting it
here is my code:

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("SystemInfo", "System", "S");

    request.setAttribute("JVMVendor", System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();

    jsonResult.put("JVMVendor", System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
    jsonResult.put("JVMVersion", System.getProperty("java.version"));
    jsonResult.put("JVMVendorURL", System.getProperty("java.vendor.url"));
    jsonResult.put("OSName", System.getProperty("os.name"));
    jsonResult.put("OSVersion", System.getProperty("os.version"));
    jsonResult.put("OSArchitectire", System.getProperty("os.arch"));

    response.getWriter().write(jsonResult.toString());


    return mav;             // return modelandview object
}
```

and in my jsp file I am using:

```
Ext.onReady(function(response) {
 //Ext.MessageBox.alert('Hello', 'The DOM is ready!');
 var showExistingScreen = function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url                     : 'system.htm',
        method                  : 'POST',
        scope                   : this,
        success: function ( response ) {                
            var existingValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);           
          }
    });
};

return showExistingScreen();
```

});

Comment: Are you talking about passing values to your jsp, or passing JSON to a page through an ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing what your title is asking for...

in java,

```
mav.addObject("ThingOne", "value of thing one.");
mav.addObject("ThingTwo", "value of thing two.");
```

in the jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>

...

<c:out value="${ThingOne}"/><br />
<c:out value="${ThingOne}"/>

...
```

should give you:

```
...
value of thing one.
value of thing two.
...
```